# Why can't I split this python list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have some code to parse an apache log file(`start_search`, and `end_search` are date strings of the format found in an apache log):

```
with open("/var/log/apache2/access.log",'r') as log:
    from itertools import takewhile, dropwhile
    s_log = dropwhile(lambda L: start_search not in L, log)
    e_log = takewhile(lambda L: end_search not in L, s_log)
    query = [line for line in e_log if re.search(r'GET /(.+veggies|.+fruits)',line)]

    import csv
    query_dict = csv.DictReader(query,fieldnames=('ip','na-1','na-2','time', 'zone', 'url', 'refer', 'client'),quotechar='"',delimiter=" ")

    import re
    veggies = [ x for x in query_dict if re.search('veggies',x['url']) ]
    fruits = [ x for x in query_dict if re.search('fruits',x['url']) ]
```

The second list generator is always empty; that is, if I switch the order of the last two lines:

```
    fruits = [ x for x in query_dict if re.search('fruits',x['url']) ]
    veggies = [ x for x in query_dict if re.search('veggies',x['url']) ]
```

the second list is always empty.

Why? (and how can I populate the `fruits` and `veggies` lists?)

Comment: Calling it `query_dict` doesn't make it a `dict`.

Comment: @kindall Perhaps a more constructive comment would have been "'csv.DictReader' doesn't return a list dictionaries, but rather an iterator".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only loop over iterators *once*; `query_dict` is an iterator that once scanned through for `veggies` cannot be iterated over again to search for `fruits`.

Don't use list comprehensions here. Loop over `query_dict` *once*, inspecting each entry for both `veggies` and `fruits`:

```
veggies = []
fruits = []

for x in query_dict:
    if re.search('veggies',x['url']):
         veggies.append(x)
    if re.search('fruits',x['url']):
         fruits.append(x)
```

The alternatives would be to:

- recreate the `csv.DictReader()` object for the `fruits` list:

  ```
  query_dict = csv.DictReader(query,fieldnames=('ip','na-1','na-2','time', 'zone', 'url', 'refer', 'client'),quotechar='"',delimiter=" ")
  veggies = [ x for x in query_dict if re.search('veggies',x['url']) ]
  query_dict = csv.DictReader(query,fieldnames=('ip','na-1','na-2','time', 'zone', 'url', 'refer', 'client'),quotechar='"',delimiter=" ")
  fruits = [ x for x in query_dict if re.search('fruits',x['url']) ]
  ```

  This does double work; you loop over the full dataset twice.
- use [`itertools.tee()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to 'clone' the iterator:

  ```
  from itertools import tee
  veggies_query_dict, fruits_query_dict = tee(query_dict)
  veggies = [ x for x in veggies_query_dict if re.search('veggies',x['url']) ]
  fruits = [ x for x in fruits_query_dict if re.search('fruits',x['url']) ]
  ```

  This ends up caching all of `query_dict` in the `tee` buffer, requiring twice the memory for the same task, until `fruits` empties out the buffer again.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations; super appreciated.